# Angular canActivate guard service not working correctly

Tags: angular, service, routes, auth-guard

I implemented a simple auth service and auth guard:
auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  isAuthed: boolean = false;


  constructor() { }

  login(user: string, password: string): void {

    this.isAuthed = false;
    if (user === 'admin' && password === 'admin') {
      this.isAuthed = true;
    }
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.isAuthed;
    }

}
```

auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { first, Observable, of, take } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    console.log("inside authGuard canActivate:", this.authService.isAuthenticated());
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

}
```

but it always returns false after I already logged in inside the form, and I thought the authservice is a global singleton...

my Router module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './app/about/about/about.component';
import { TestComponent } from './app/about/test/test.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './app/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './app/auth.service';
import { BookCardComponent } from './app/book/book-card/book-card.component';
import { BookDetailsComponent } from './app/book/book-details/book-details.component';
import { BookListComponent } from './app/book/book-list/book-list.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'books',
    // children: [{
    //   path: '',
    //   component: BookListComponent,
    // }, {
    //   path: ':isbn',
    //   component: BookDetailsComponent,
    // }]
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
  },
  {
  path: 'books',
  component: BookListComponent,
  },
  {
  path: 'books/:isbn',
  component: BookDetailsComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BookModule } from './book/book.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app-routing.module';
import { AboutModule } from './about/about.module';
import { BmIsbnPipe } from './book/shared/bm-isbn.pipe';
import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about/about-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AboutRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BookModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AboutModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

has it to do something with my book-module.ts ? Do I have to import the authservice or authguard inside the providers array there? or is it already provided globally from the app-module.ts?

**EDIT: I Think I might have found the problem:**

inside my book-card-component.html, I have the  tag link with "target=_blank", so it always opens the link inside a new tab. But I thought it does not affect the singleton apiservice, it appears it looses its set class fields when opening in a new browser tab... weird.

```
<ng-container>
  <p [ngStyle]="customStyle">{{content?.title}}</p>
  <img src={{content?.cover}} />
  <p [ngClass]="'test'">Author: {{content?.author }}</p>
  <p>Abstract: {{content?.abstract}}</p>
  <p>Description: {{content?.description}}</p>
  <p>ISBN: {{content?.isbn | bmIsbn}}</p>
  <a [routerLink]="[content?.isbn]" **target="_blank"**>Link to Book-Details</a>
</ng-container>
<!-- <pre [ngStyle]="{color: 'orange'}"><code>{{content | json}}</code></pre> -->
```

Comment: When you refresh the page or open your application in a new tab / window, you are creating a separate instance of your application. If you want data to persist across all instances, you need to store it somehow, either in local storage or in a database. I would suggest just using an authentication service like Firebase. Auth services will generally sign in using a database, then save a token to the browser cache.

Comment: ok thanks, that clarifies it

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mentionned in your edit, I would guess that the problem is target="_blank"

In fact this behaviour is not that weird: if you create a route for the component and load that route in a new tab (with target="_blank") you will end up bootstrapping the app again. So in fact it's another instance and all your not persisted data would be lost.